# Inkscape execution "cannot proceed because libicuuc65.dll was not found"

Tags: windows-10, inkscape

I'm trying to start inkscape 1.1.1 on my Windows 10 system, and am getting this error message:

> **The code execution cannot  proceed because libicuuc65.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.**

Inkscape did use to work - but I haven't run it in quite a while. I should perhaps mention I've installed it via Chocolatey.

1. Why is this happening?
2. Reinstalling inkscape **does not help**. What can I actually do to overcome this and get it to start?

Comment: I'd certainly have tried the reinstall before even asking here - because otherwise that's going to be the first, obvious, suggestion.

Comment: @Tetsujin: See edit.

Comment: KK, cool. We at least exhausted that avenue. :)

Comment: Where exactly is libicuuc65.dll located on your system? Essentially the file cannot be found on your system, it’s a [linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404636/libstdc-6-dll-not-found/6405064#6405064) problem, essentially solved by making sure the file can be found. Did this application work at any point?

Comment: Uninstall it with Chocolatey and download the installer. The Chocolatey package is obviously the problem. Be sure you are running the stable version also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem as OP (Inkscape did use to work - but I haven't run it in quite a while), but I installed via the Windows installer package (.msi) from the official site.

After turning to the old-fashioned .exe installer, the problem is resolved. I'm not sure about the reason. BTW, I checked my C:\Program Files\Inkscape folder, but there's no libicuuc65.dll file even now.

---

I opened an issue in Inkscape's gitlab page, hopefully someone will finally figure out the root of the problem:

https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/6556

Comment: This worked for me, although TBH I used the v1.2 beta .exe installer.

Comment: @einpoklum FYI, I reinstalled with inkscape-1.1.2_2022-02-05_b8e25be833-x64.exe on Windows 10, 21H1.

Answer (score 1):

Just realised I had two versions on the system, uninstalled both and reinstalled Inkscape to a different drive, which fixed it for me.